# run socket.io connect with multiple events

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How can I run multiple socket events/socket.on() on the server? ex.

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();
server = require('http').createServer(app);
io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

server.listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

        socket.on('node1', function(data){
                io.sockets.emit('node1 message', data);
        });
        socket.on('node2', function(data){
                io.sockets.emit('node2 message', data);
        });

});
```

When I run the client as follow, the message gets broadcast.

```
socket.emit('node1','Hello World');
```

but on node2, nothing comes through.

```
socket.emit('node2','Hello World');
```

Thanks!

Sorry,

This is what I run on the client side (sending data).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>nodes_update</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://192.168.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">

    var socket = io('http://192.168.0.1:8080/');
        socket.emit('<?php echo $_REQUEST["node"] ?>','<?php echo $_REQUEST["node_message"] ?>');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

On the receive side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script src="http://192.168.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">

            var socket = io('http://192.168.0.1:8080/');
            socket.on('<?php echo $_REQUEST["node"] ?>', function(data) {

                // plot_data(data);

            });
</script>
</html>



<?php echo $_REQUEST["node"] ?> //is the node number ex "node1" or "node2"
<?php echo $_REQUEST["node_message"] ?> //is the data of the node ex "Temp-90".
```

http://192.168.0.1/show_node_data.php?node=node1+message&node_message=Temp-90

this is to plot multiple node data

Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce. What does your client-side code look like?

Comment: hi, on page node_data.php

<script src="http://192.168.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
 var socket = io('http://192.168.0.1:8080/');
 socket.emit('<?php echo $_REQUEST["node"]; ?>','<?php echo $_REQUEST["node_data"]; ?>');
</script>

Comment: Please add that to your question. Also, I don't see listeners for both types of messages (`node1 message` and `node2 message`).

Comment: What do those `$_REQUEST` variables resolve to?

Comment: When the server receives an event called `node2`, it will broadcast an event called `node2 message`. You need a specific listener for that event in your client, and I'm not sure if you have.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I recoded the server to use mysql to do a node name lookup and then send data to the page with the node name found else send nothing.

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();
server = require('http').createServer(app);
io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
server.listen(8080);
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection('mysql://moo:password@localhost/node_db');
connection.connect();





io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

        socket.on('send message', function(data){
                var token = data.token;
                var message = data.message;

                var queryToken = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM `node_token` where node_token = ' + connection.escape(token);

                connection.query(queryToken, function(err, rows, fields) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        //console.log(rows[0].num);
                        //console.log(token);
                        //console.log(message);

                        var node_name = rows[0].num;

                        if(node_name != 0) {
                                console.log("Node name found in DB");
                                io.sockets.emit(token, message);
                        }else{
                        console.log("Node name not found in db");
                        }

                });
        });

});
```

DB table;

```
+----+------------+---------------+
| id | node_token | node_owner_id |
+----+------------+---------------+
|  2 | node1      |             1 |
|  3 | node2      |             1 |
+----+------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

send data page "node_update.php?node=node1&node_message=temp-90"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>nodes_update</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://192.168.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">

    var token = <?php echo $_REQUEST["node"]; ?>;
    var message = <?php echo $_REQUEST["node_message"]; ?>;

    var socket = io('http://192.168.0.1:8080/');
    socket.emit('send message',{token:token, message:message});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

recieve data page "node_get_data.php?node=node1"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script src="http://192.168.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">

            var socket = io('http://192.168.0.1:8080/');
            socket.on('<?php echo $_REQUEST["node"]; ?>', function(data) {

                //plot(data);

            });
</script>
</html>
```

This way I can use unlimited nodes and just add them to the db.

Thanks for all the help!!